# Pytest: Only run linter checks (pytest-flake8), don't run tests

Tags: python, pytest

I'm using the [pytest-flake8](https://pypi.org/project/pytest-flake8/) plugin to lint my Python code.
Everytime I run the linting like this:

```
pytest --flake8
```

In addition to the linting, all tests are run. 
But I would like to run the linter checks only.

How can I configure pytest so it only lints the code but skips all my tests, preferrably via commandline (or conftest.py) - **without having to add skip markers to my tests**?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

flake8 tests are marked with the `flake8` marker, so you can select only those by running:

`pytest --flake8 -m flake8`

Answer (score 4):

Pytests `--ignore <<path>>` option also works well here if all of your tests are in one directory.

I usually hide this behind a make command. In this case my `Makefile` and `tests` directory are both at the root of the repository.

```
.PHONY: lint

lint:
    pytest --flake8 --ignore tests
```

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem and after some digging, I realized that I just want to run `flake8`:

`flake8 <path to folder>`

That's it. No need to run anything else as your `flake8` [configuration](http://flake8.pycqa.org/en/latest/user/configuration.html#configuring-flake8) is independent of PyTest.

Comment: @ifischer I would love to know why you think providing an alternative working solution doesn't answer the question. I know you ask explicitly for a `pytest` based solution, but in my opinion, this is not the best way to go. As I said I had the same problem and I realized that it takes to much effort and adds additional (in my opinion unnecessary) complexity to a project, when I tempered with `pytest` itself. Just running `flake8` is a simple and clean alternative and solves the given problem.

Comment: I do this all the time, too, but it's not sufficient if the files you want to lint are ones that contain tests, which is what I think the OP was asking about.

Comment: The reason I want to run linting within pytest is that it makes me able to output my linting checks as HTML/XML, so it can be more nicely integrated into CI pipeline. All linting and test results will be in the same result format.

Also since I am now able to split running quick linting checks first and slow tests afterwards, my pipeline will fail quickly.

Answer (score 1):

You can alter the test run logic yourself, for example by ignoring collected tests when `--flake8` arg passed:

```
# conftest.py

def pytest_collection_modifyitems(session, config, items):
    if config.getoption('--flake8'):
        items[:] = [item for item in items if item.get_closest_marker('flake8')]
```

Now only flake8 tests will be executed, the rest will be just ignored.

Answer (score 0):

After some more thoughts, this is the solution I came up with - and it works with pytest 5.3.5 (`get_marker` from https://stackoverflow.com/a/52891274/319905 does not exist anymore).

It allows me to run specific linting checks via commandline.
Since I still like to keep the option of running both linting checks and tests, I added a flag telling pytest if it should only do linting.

Usage:

```
# Run only flake8 and mypy, no tests
pytest --lint-only --flake8 --mypy

# Run tests and flake8
pytest --flake8
```

Code:

```
# conftest.py
def pytest_addoption(parser):
    parser.addoption(
        "--lint-only",
        action="store_true",
        default=False,
        help="Only run linting checks",
    )


def pytest_collection_modifyitems(session, config, items):
    if config.getoption("--lint-only"):
        lint_items = []
        for linter in ["flake8", "black", "mypy"]:
            if config.getoption(f"--{linter}"):
                lint_items.extend(
                    [item for item in items if item.get_closest_marker(linter)]
                )
        items[:] = lint_items
```

Comment: Only to clarify - `get_marker` was replaced by `get_closest_marker`, see [Updating code](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/historical-notes.html#update-marker-code). Updated the answer.

Comment: @hoefling thanks, thats better then having to import each item class. I also updated my solution using get_closest_marker

Comment: How would you annotate the types? The parser is a  `from _pytest.config.argparsing import Parser`, but what are session / config / items?

Comment: `from _pytest.config import Config` for the config, I guess.